# Timeout loops don't work

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout

I have a function set in a variable that is called several times and should loop after the first time it's through.

After vaildating my code I think it's a slip somewhere, but I can't find it

**Here's my code**:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var tre_heartbeat_small;
    playing = function () {
        tre_heartbeat_small = function () {
            //stuff it does
        }
    }

    function heartbeatloop() {
        function () {
            playing();
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            playing();
        }, 800, heartbeatloop)
    }
    heartbeatloop();
}, 1500);
```

And here's a **fiddle** for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nRwkz/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nRwkz/1/

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatlyt it still is not looping ;)

Comment: Any time you call `playing()` it will set `tre_heartbeat_small` to a new anonymous function - nothing more. When calling `heartbeatloop()` you're creating an anonymous function which would call `playing()` if it would be executed, but it isn't. Last but not least [`setTimeout`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html) can have more than 2 arguments but anything beyond the second will be passed as parameters to the function passed as first argument. IE can't handle more than two arguments at all.

Comment: And the `//stuff it does` won't work as expected as the animations are asynchronous and will run at the "same time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't admit as a 3rd parameter the name of a function.

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). 
You can not loop magically with setTimeout :)

I would recommend you to make use of [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead or use closure functions and a proper `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you're already using jQuery I've set up an example without an explicit usage of `setTimeout` or `setInterval` at all - just out of curiosity :)
All the magic is done with [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
var timer = 500,
    animateLow = function (callback) {
        $.when($("#test").animate({
            height: '977px',
            width: '1080px',
            left: '49.5%',
            top: '370px'
        }, timer)).done(callback);
    },
    animateHigh = function (callback) {
        $.when($("#test").animate({
            height: '944px',
            width: '1044px',
            left: '50%',
            top: '380px'
        }, timer)).done(callback);
    };

function heartbeatloop() {
    animateLow(function () {
        animateHigh(heartbeatloop);
    });
}

heartbeatloop();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL2aY/1/)

**Update**
The code for the requirement from the comments

```
var element = $("#test"),
    animate_timer = 1000, // duration of the animation
    beat = [{
        // method for animation
        method: function() {
            element.text("low");
            return element.animate({height:'977px',width:'1080px',left:'49.5%',top:'370px'},animate_timer);
        },
        // time after which the next animation should start
        timeout: 0
    }, {
        method: function() {
            element.text("normal");
            return element.animate({height:'944px',width:'1044px',left:'50%',top:'380px'},animate_timer);
        },
        timeout: 1000
    }, {
        method: function() {
            element.text("high");
            return element.animate({height:'995px',width:'1100px',left:'49.3%',top:'360px'},animate_timer);
        },
        timeout: 3000
    }
];

function beatIt(idx) {
    idx = idx || 0;

    $.when(beat[idx].method())     // start the animation
     .done(function() {            // when finished start the next step in <timeout> milliseconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            beatIt((idx + 1) % beat.length);    // next step with reset after last element
        }, beat[idx].timeout);
    });
}

beatIt();    // start the beating
```

Comment: That's a great one ;)
Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Maybe you can tell my why this http://jsfiddle.net/dL2aY/2/
Is not working correctly!
I just want the loop animation to
do a low raise, go back to normal
pause for 1 sec
do a high raise, go back to normal
pause for 3 sec
start over

Comment: There were some syntax errors, missing elements (selector didn't fit an element), unnecessary code. I'm a little bit lazy at the moment so I set up my own version of your requirement with some comments for explanation - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YcZXY/)

Comment: This is awesome! Great one! Thank you very much for your "lazy" work!

Comment: It's just a modified snippet I've used some time ago =)